# REGEX- How can I get the first date after a underscore?

Tags: regex

I just started to learn Regex but I'm struggling to get the first date of the following string:

```
gs://dcdt_-dcm_account/dcm_account_click_2016070510_20160631_165654_2592254.csv.gz
```

I want to get 20160705

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
^.*dcm_account_click_(\d{8}).*$
```

The `(\d{8})` term is a *capture group*, and tells the regex engine to extract it and make it available.

`\d{8}` matches 8 numbers in sequence, which is what you are after.

**Demo:**

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xQ0uL9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
k_(\d{8})
```

or with a positive lookbehind

```
(?<=k_)(\d{8})
```

And then access to the capturing group.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS9tS8/1)**

Btw, if you just use `(\d{8})` and look for the first match it also will work.

Answer (score 0):

If there are **no** digits before the first date, you might very well get along with:

```
^\D*(\d+) # beginning of the line/string, followed by NON-digits
          # capture the digits afterwards
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hL5yM6/2).